# How to make four 7 s equal to 4 and to 10?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

> How to make four 7 s equal to 4 and to 10?

f(7, 7, 7, 7) = 1:  7/7 * 7/7 = 1
f(7, 7, 7, 7) = 2:  7/7 + 7/7 = 2
f(7, 7, 7, 7) = 3:  (7+7+7)/7 = 3
f(7, 7, 7, 7) = 4:  ?
        .
        .
f(7, 7, 7, 7) = 10:  ?
I can also make four 7s equal to 5, 6 , 7 , 8 and 9 by using square root and lg plus +, - * and / but not 4 and 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, puzzles tend to be swept away at this server (At least my experience with my puzzles). Hence, I decided to upvote it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use logs for $5,6,7,8,9$, but $\sqrt{7\times7}=7$ is useful.

Comment: $$7+(7-7)\cdot 7=7$$ $$7-\frac{7+7}{7}=5$$ $$7+\frac{7+7}{7}=9$$

Comment: $$\frac{7\cdot 7+7}{7}=8$$ $$\frac{7\cdot 7-7}{7}=6$$

Comment: Stop asking the same question multiple times, please.

Comment: So, upto $10$ , we only need "+,-,*,/". We can reach $12$ as well : $\frac{77+7}{7}=12$. What about $11$ ? $\frac{77}{7}$ would work, but how can we use $4$ sevens ?

Comment: FWIW f(7,7,7,7) is both terrible and useless notation.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{77}{7}- 7=4$$

$$\frac{77-7}{7}=10$$

Comment: Just $\frac{77}{7}-7$ is easier for 4

Comment: @Joffan I my god, didn't get this! I become old!

Answer (score 0):

How about this: $|\{7,7,7,7\}|=4$. Seems obvious but don't know if it falls in line with acceptable mathematical operations!

Comment: But $\{7, 7, 7, 7\}=\{7\}$ . . .

Comment: Here's a way to salvage the idea: $|\{7\}|+|\{7\}|+|\{7\}|+|\{7\}|=1+1+1+1=4$.

Comment: Quite right! The important lesson is to not answer posts late at night. Right idea but poorly executed - thanks for salvaging it @Theophile !